# "College" vs "undergraduate-education"

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

As this site is about mathematics education, it seems that [college](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/college) and [undergraduate-education](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/undergraduate-education) are redundant and should be made synonymous.

**Is it beneficial to have both [college](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/college) and [undergraduate-education](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/undergraduate-education) as distinct tags?**

Comment: I'm beware that I tagged some of my questions with this tag to emphasize that they are **not** related to school. I'm not completely known to the US system, but should there be an "university" tag or would that by a synomym of college?

Comment: I could've sworn that this type of thing has been asked before and it was stated that it will become a non-issue once the Beta goes live through some tool. I don't recall exactly, but I believe Brian mentioned it.

Comment: @MarkusKlein In the US system, the term "university" usually refers specifically to an institution that offers both undergraduate and graduate degrees.

Comment: @DavidG It's possible to define [tag synonyms](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) as sonn as someone from the community has reached the privilege to do so (I guess in 1-2 days), but we have to decide if want to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In view of this discussion I approved an existing suggestion to make college a synoym of undergraduate-education.

If somebody wishes to use college for a more specific purpose please let me know so that synonym can be cancelled.

Answer (score 12):

The [college](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/college) tag as it is *currently used* should be dropped.

Currently it is used to indicate (beginning) tertiary education, matching common informal usage in the US. Yet, already in other English speaking countries, as far as I understand, this does not really fit or could be ambigous.

I refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/College for an overview of other usages.

There is the extra issue that in other languages words similar to college exist with a different meaning, for example, in France "collège" is the standard name for the school for 11-15 year old.

If one wants a tag like it, I would recommend [university](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/university) A word similar to university with about the same meaning exists in **many** languages.

The tag [undergraduate-education](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/undergraduate-education) seems much better and more in line with the other tags of this type we have, also containing education.

(In theory there might be a place for [college](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/college), or even more particular thing like [liberal-arts-college](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/liberal-arts-college) for question specific to this type of institution. Yet, this is not at all the current usage and I think not the subject of the question.)

Comment: I completely agree.

Comment: The "university" tag would not be compatible with American English, because liberal arts colleges are typically not referred to as universities.  The "undergraduate-education" tag would work fine.  Alternatively, what about "higher-education"?

Comment: @JimBelk yes, that is why I did not recommend a university tag; I pointed out it would be relatively better as it should be wider *understood* what is the *intent*. Higher-education seems alright, but is a bit broad, and I if we have it this braod I would use rather tertiary-education (in line with primary, secondary).  The advanatag of undergraduate-ed is that it more specific.

Answer (score 11):

I think that 'college' should be eliminated, as it is highly ambiguous, especially in an international context.  'undergraduate-education' is much better.

Comment: How is "college" ambiguous in an international context?

Comment: @JimBelk please see my answer.