# Tag synonyms handling

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

I got confused about the tag synonyms, in particular whether the "suggest synonym" feature is "X has a synonym Y" or "X is a synonym of Y". Is there a way to remove master/synonym relation other than downvoting it? It wouldn't be a problem if it weren't for the fact that it seems impossible to have two options $X \to Y$ and $Y \to X$ open at the same time.

(Context: I wanted to suggest [undergraduate-education](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/undergraduate-education) $\gets$ [college](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/college) pair as discussed [here](https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102/college-vs-undergraduate-education).)

**Edit:** Already resolved (i.e. enough people downvoted the inappropriate relation).

Comment: Could somebody with score at least +5 in [tag:college] please add a downvote to the tag proposal http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/tags/college/synonyms so that the one created inadvertently goes away. (This seem to be the intent of  OP who created it, AFAIK it is inconsequentlial yet necessary see my answer; the -1 there was me btw.)

Comment: @quid Indeed, that was my intent, so the wrong mapping goes away.

Answer (score 3):

When you start at a tag T and type in S as a synonym suggestion, then you propose that T stays an actual tag, and S becomes merely a synonym of T. This is typically noted T <-- S.

This means  everything tagged S will/would be (automatically) retagged to T. Being a synnonym is highly asymmetric here, and thus it is also not possible that one has both directions at the same time.

As you suspect, in the case you mention it was created the wrong way around. If the current one would be approved we would get [college](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/college) <-- [undergraduate-education](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/undergraduate-education) and thus keep [college](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/college), which is opposite to the discussion.

I do not know how to get rid of it other than by dwon-voting; it appears one cannot cancel ones own proposals.

As a very general note: the synonm creation only via proposiing and voting on main does often not work well as there is not enough visibility; it can be more efficient to propse synonyms on meta, and we might want to create a dedicated thread for this.